# json format output from JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

```
var singleItems = new List<Products>();

singleItems.Add(new Products() { product_id = 1, title = "Bryon Hetrick", price = 50 });
singleItems.Add(new Products() { product_id = 2, title = "Nicole Wilcox", price = 20 });

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(serializer);
```

From above example code i am getting Json output like bellow.

```
[{"product_id":1,"title":"Bryon Hetrick","price":50},
 {"product_id":2,"title":"Nicole Wilcox","price":20}]
```

But my Json need one more value called- "config" also i need whole data formatted exactly like bellow. How to edit my c# code to achieve that value?

```
{ "products":[{"product_id":"B071H6TBM5","title":"New Iphone 5S","price":"23.45"},{"product_id":"B071DM968J","title":"Iphone 4 old","price":"23.45"}],"config":{"token":"","Site":"Us","Mode":"ListMyItem"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a `Config` class with the properties you require and then a composite class with Prodcuts and Config, i.e. ProductConfig:

```
public class Products 
{
   public string product_id { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string price { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
  public string token { get; set; }
  public string site { get; set; }
  public string mode { get; set; }
}

public class ProductConfig 
{
   public List<Products> Products { get; set; }
   public Config Config { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create/populate the `ProductConfig` class with the new properties.

```
public string SerializeProductConfig()
{
   ProductConfig pc = new ProductConfig();
   pc.Config = new Config { token = "DDTest", site = "US", mode = "Test Mode" };
   pc.Products = new List<Products>();
   pc.Products.Add(new Products() { product_id = "1", title = "Bryon Hetrick", price = "50" });
   pc.Products.Add(new Products() { product_id = "2", title = "Nicole Wilcox", price = "20" });

   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   return serializer.Serialize(pc);
}
```

and serialize the `ProductConfig` object using the `JavaScript` serializer or [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which will give you the following `JSON`

```
{ // ProductConfig
  "Products": [
    {
      "product_id": "1",
      "title": "Bryon Hetrick",
      "price": "50"
    },
    {
      "product_id": "2",
      "title": "Nicole Wilcox",
      "price": "20"
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "token": "DDTest",
    "site": "US",
    "mode": "Test Mode"
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without making that model class?

Comment: @Johnpoe - the serializer looks at the object you provide it and converts it to JSON, therefore you would have to modify your RegisteredUsers class to include the Config properties for the output. This may break your design, so I would recommend having an intermediary class as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Johnpoe - you are attempted to serialize the JavaScript serializer. You want to be serializing the C# object.  I have amended my answer so it is clearer for you. I have also tested out the code via: 
http://csharp2json.azurewebsites.net/

I would recommend you try that also.